# logstash and grok convert NUMBER to integer

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I'm trying to use grok and logstash to index some numeric datas. Datas structure is something like:

```
[integer,integer,integer,...,integer]
```

I created a index pattern in logstash, and using grok i write this filter:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[%{NUMBER:opcode:int},%{NUMBER:sender:int},%{NUMBER:alertbitmap:int},%{NUMBER:bat:int},%{NUMBER:ant:int},%{NUMBER:resbat:int},%{NUMBER:temp:int},%{NUMBER:presatm:int},%{NUMBER:umid:int},%{NUMBER:vertical:int},%{NUMBER:analog1:int},%{NUMBER:analog2:int},%{NUMBER:analog3:int},%{NUMBER:analog4:int},%{NUMBER:spostam:int},%{NUMBER:contporta1:int},%{NUMBER:contporta2:int},%{NUMBER:digital1:int},%{NUMBER:digital2:int},%{NUMBER:digital3:int},%{NUMBER:digital4:int},%{NUMBER:time:int}\]" }
}
```

but when I explore index pattern in logstash the type is still string. How can i resolve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: With data like this, use the dissect filter, you'll get better performance. And to convert a field, you can use convert option of the mutate filter.

Comment: Though if the mapping was created in elasticsearch, you'll have to delete it and start over